# Date format in UNIX

Tags: date

How can I show date in YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+ZZZZ format in LINUX? I need to write the creation date of a file say file1 in another file say file2 in given format. Help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 13):

The date format you are referring to is ISO 8601. Use the `-I` option to the `date` command to format dates according to this format (the `s` specifies precision up to integral seconds):

```
$ date -Is
2013-10-08T10:48:03+0300
```

To obtain the last modification time of a file (in seconds since the epoch), use the `%Y` format specifier with the `stat` command:

```
$ stat -c %Y file1
1378818806
```

Combining these two, use `date -d` to format the output of `stat -c`:

```
$ date -Is -d @`stat -c %Y file1`
2013-09-10T16:13:26+0300
```

So this is the statement that does what you need:

```
$ date -Is -d @`stat -c %Y file1` > file2
```

Comment: Too bad none of `date` manual page, `info` documentation or `--help` output mention the `-I` option. I finally found it here https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Options-for-date.html and of course in the source code too.

Comment: @jlliagre `man date` (from coreutils 8.20 on Ubuntu 13.04) shows this option: `-I[TIMESPEC],--iso-8601[=TIMESPEC] output date and time in ISO 8601 format`.

Comment: Thanks, the documentation was just lagging then, I'm using 12.10.

Answer (score 5):

You can display a date that way with this command:

```
$ date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z
2013-10-08T07:38:45+0200
```

Many file systems do not store a file creation date so there is not always a method to get it. If the file has never been modified since its creation, this would work:

```
$ date -r file1 +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z > file2
$ cat file2
2013-10-08T07:32:52+0200
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you?

```
ls -c -l file1 --time-style="+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z" > file 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining my [previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/355267/134479) and [that of @jlliagre](https://askubuntu.com/a/355196/134479), the most concise way to do what you want is:

```
date -Is -r file1 > file2
```