# Where the function, to see date in terminal, is saved?

Tags: command-line, bash, date, functions

I mean, there isn't any function written in ~/.bashrc which can be used for showing date.

Comment: `date` command can be used from terminal.

`man date`
`info coreutils 'date invocation'`

Comment: Why do you think it is a function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date format in UNIX](http://askubuntu.com/questions/355188/date-format-in-unix) To show the date type `date` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have functions and alias'es in your .bashrc or .profile implementing different features, and you have built-in functions in bash (or other shells). And some functionality are implemented as binary programs in /bin, /usr/bin or elsewhere.

You can use the command `type` to show where a 'program' is:

```
$ type date
date is /bin/date
$ type test
test is a shell builtin
$ type ls
ls is aliased to 'ls --color=auto'
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
```